# Can classes be executed in parallel mode in testNG

Tags: eclipse, testing, testng

testNG documentation says, there are 2 parallel mode possible in testNG. In testng.xml, we can set either parallel="methods" or parallel="tests". There is no scope for parallel="classes".

But, in eclipse, after adding testNG plugin, i can see option for parallel="classes".

So, my query is : is it possible/correct to set parallel="classes".

Answer (score 0):

Yes parallel="classes" is possible. you can run your test classes parallely. you just need to specify thread-count as to how many parallel test classes should run parallely.

Answer (score 0):

Actually TestNG doc says there are more parallel options
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests